# Is there any way I can use my Wii U to play movies I have on my computer?

Tags: wii-u

Is there any way I can use my Wii U to play movies I have on my computer? So if I have purchased a movie through iTunes for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can setup a Plex server on your home PC. Plex server essentially hosts your videos and other media for use from the home, and supports many platforms such as the iPhone/Android, Chromecast, Smart TVs, other PCs, and major consoles.

There isn't a Wii-U app directly to support it, however you can use the Wii-U's built in web-browser with ease.

The basics for setting up a server is beyond a hand-written tutorial for this website, especially as the software changes over time. A [quick Google search](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=plex%20tutorial&safe=off) will need you plenty of high-quality tutorials for your device in question.

Comment: I set it up according to [this](http://nintendo.about.com/od/nintendowiibasics/ss/How-To-Stream-Media-To-The-Wii-U-Plex-Media-Server_4.htm) tutorial, and when I try to stream a TV show, I get `Error Code: 112-2404 Could not load video. Try Reloading the page?`

Comment: What format is the video? Plex should properly transcode the videos automatically to .mp4 which is supported on the wii-u browser. Is it still building the library on the PC?

Comment: It's from my iTunes library, which has it as an mpeg-4. It lists it as "recently added", so I'm pretty sure it's on there? I'm not exactly sure. The videos also don't play in Chrome, or on my Nexus 4. I posted on their forum to try to figure it out.